# Save a super class as a sub class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jar, save

I hava a `UserClass` entity and `AddUserClassPanel` in my jar files. I want to use `AddUserClasssPanel` so that this panel saves a `UserClass`.

Now I want add a condition for saving a `UserClass`. For this reason I create a `UserClassImpl` that extends `UserClass` and overrides the `save` method in it. To do this I create a `UserClass` table in my `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Now when a `userclass.save()` call in `AddUserPanel` is executed it should call `userclassImpl.save()` method instead so a `userclassImpl` is stored in my database.

How I can do this?

Comment: Probably start reading here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html

Comment: thanks peter , but i can't find what i want in this documentation. :(

Comment: Please give some thought about how your question looks to the outside world. If you cannot be bothered to capitalize your sentences, "i"'s etc. then you will get much less attention.

Comment: Hi Maarten,  I want To add Some Condition for saving a UserClass(that is jar file)  in my dataBase. So I create a sub-class(UserClassImpl) . Now I want to use a AddUserPanel(jar file) that save a UserClass. I want to save UserClassImpl(instead UserClass) in addUserPanel but I cant change AddUserPanel beacause it is a jar file .